# ASP.Net API Consumption in PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, api, integration

Hi All Experts,
               As i am new in PHP but i have good experience in ASP.Net. I want to integrate my Website developed in PHP with my ASP.net Project and SQL Server. For this i have developed an API and call it in PHP which is not working for me. Kindly guide me where i am missing. PHP Source code is given below.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://msplhe.ddns.net:1440/tracking/usercon/sms/89410032056412647926/31.49976>/74.36318/');
//curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'www.google.com.pk');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 7520.63.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'cURL crawler');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $html;
```

When i execute this on server it did not show any result and no error on page. But when i comment my API and uncomment www.google.com.pk it shows google search me on page. I am stuck in it. Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The url has a `>` in it - is this a simple typo? Without that `>` in the url the page resolves to an xml document `<string>Done</string>` - with the `>` in the url it generates an error

Comment: Thanks for in time response.
as i have used without ">" in source code but same situation exist.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, I believe, was the `>` in the url - this was causing an application error ( you can change the error page too btw )

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://msplhe.ddns.net:1440/tracking/usercon/sms/89410032056412647926/31.49976/74.36318/'); /* Remove ">" from url here */
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 7520.63.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'cURL crawler');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close( $ch );/* don't forget to close curl */
echo $html;

output
------
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">Done</string>
```

Comment: Thanks RamRaider for in time response.
as i have used without ">" in source code but same situation exist.

Comment: What is the expected output? I see an xml document with only one element ( as shown in answer ) - what do expect to see??

Comment: Dafinatly, as you shared output i want to see this output on screen after calling the API.
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">Done</string>

Comment: That's what it does show - or rather, in the webbrowser it simply show "Done" - the xml element tags are not shown in the browser but they are there!

Comment: wow great hearings,
dear sir kindly share source code that you have did.